# Как изменить количество аргументов в указателе на функцию на С?

Tags: c, указатели

Вот например у меня есть две функции с разным количеством аргументов:

```
void print_ab(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
}

void print_a(int a)
{
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

И вот допустим пример програмы:

```
int main()
{
    void(*f)(int,int)
    f = print_ab;
    f(5,3);
}
```

И вот как использовать этот же указатель только для print_a функции? Тобиш как поменять количество аргументов в этом указателе?
Варианты типу этого не подходят:

```
    f = print_a;
    f(5,0);
```

Comment: а передавайте массив

Comment: Если функция ожидает два аргумента, то она должна получить два аргумента. Кроме массива есть ещё вариант написать только одну функцию с переменным количеством аргументов. P.S. В объявлении указателя на функцию звёздочка стоит не там где нужно.

Comment: сделайте все функции с произвольным кол-вом аргументов `print(...)`, тогда и указатель на эти функции будет одинаковый, а с аргументами функция внутри себя сама будет разбираться

Comment: Хорошо, как сделать функцию с произвольнім кол-вом аргументов?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic

Comment: Забавный вопрос. Примерно так -  у меня есть указатель на массив `a`. Как использовать этот указатель, чтобы он указывал на массив `b`? :)

Comment: Да, я сформулировал плохо. У меня препод говорит что можно юзать один и тот же указатель на две функции с разным количеством аргументов. И просто указать на вторую функцию, с одним аргументом, а потом вызвать f(5,0) - говорит что это тупо))). Я просто не знаю что делать((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично у меня случай был с двумя плагинами, и указателем надо было брать функции площадей разных фигур, из разных плагинов. Сообственно там разное количество аргументов, тобиш: площадь круга - один аргумент (r), площадь треугольника через три стороны - три аргумента (a,b,c). Сообственно можно просто объявить вот такой указатель:

```
double (*pointer)();
```

И применять туда функции, в моём случае были плагины, тобиш `dlsym(plug, "функция")`
,и просто передавать туда **Переменные** в функцию:

```
double a = 5, b = 5, c = 5;
pointer(a,b,c);
```